# Using GoogleSheet Appscript to pull an ID from one column to a cell when another column has the number 1 in it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Column B is filled with a list of IDs, say B2 is 'w131' and B3 is 'z1122', etc.

I need Cell BW2 to be filled with one of these IDs if I put a '1' in column BY,

but it has to be the corresponding ID so putting a '1' in BY2 fills BW2 with 'w131' and putting a '1' in BY3 fills BW2 with 'z1122' etc.

I have the start of some Apps Script code here:

```
function setCalculate(){
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-iZLMiCumHmyloF62335QYOWTn14canbEb4r_7eamM/edit#gid=0");
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AutoQuoteDataBase");
  var range = srcSheet.getRange("BY2:BY");  
  var values = range.getValues();  
   
  if( values == "1"){
    
      
  }
}
```

obviously it isn't finished, or maybe this could be done with a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the column "BY" is `1`, you want to copy the value from column "B" to column "BW".
- You want to achieve this by modifying your function of `setCalculate`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var range = srcSheet.getRange("BY2:BY");  
var values = range.getValues();  
 
if( values == "1"){
  
    
}
```

##### To:

```
var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
var values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:BY" + lastRow).getValues();
var res = values.map(r => [r[76] == 1 ? r[1] : r[74]]);
srcSheet.getRange("BW2:BW" + lastRow).setValues(res);
```

- When this script is run, your goal is achieved.
- If you want to set the empty when the column "BY" is not `1`, please modify `var res = values.map(r => [r[76] == 1 ? r[1] : r[74]]);` to `var res = values.map(r => [r[76] == 1 ? r[1] : ""]);`.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From the following replying,

> however I need it to change only the cell BW2, otherwise it is perfect

How about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
var values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:BY" + lastRow).getValues();
var res = values.flatMap(r => r[76] == 1 ? [r[1]] : []);
if (res.length == 0) return;
srcSheet.getRange("BW2").setValue(res[0]);
```

Comment: Hi, this works great, however I need it to change only the cell BW2, otherwise it is perfect

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: That worked! thank you very much!

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, This code is working great, is there a way to make it also move information from column BZ and place it in cell CZ2 at the same time in the same way? I just I have no idea how to change the code myself

Comment: @Ben About your new question of `This code is working great, is there a way to make it also move information from column BZ and place it in cell CZ2 at the same time in the same way? I just I have no idea how to change the code myself`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, how about modifying to `srcSheet.getRange("CZ2").setValue(res[0]);`?

Comment: I added that underneath the original, because I still need it for the code's original purpose. I need to move information from column BZ aswell

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I added that underneath the original, because I still need it for the code's original purpose. I need to move information from column BZ aswell `, I cannot understand what you want to do. So can you add more information to [your latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71109158/7108653)? By this, I would like to try to understand it.