# How can I make the following code move information into two columns instead of one in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
function setCalculate(){
 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M/edit#gid=0");
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AutoQuoteDataBase");
  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
var values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:BY" + lastRow).getValues();
var res = values.flatMap(r => r[76] == 1 ? [r[1]] : []);
if (res.length == 0) return;
srcSheet.getRange("BW2").setValue(res[0]);
}
```

This code works perfectly for its original purpose which was to copy IDs from Column B, say B2 is 'w131' and B3 is 'z1122', etc.

I needed Cell BW2 to be filled with one of these IDs if I put a '1' in column BY,

and it has to be the corresponding ID so putting a '1' in BY2 fills BW2 with 'w131' and putting a '1' in BY3 fills BW2 with 'z1122' etc.

What I need is for the same row to be moved from column BZ into CB2 when the code is triggered.

Comment: Can't understand what you want to achieve from code, if you better elaborate that will be  better or you can share the sheet link with sample information

Comment: What the code already does is copy an ID from column B to cell BW2 when it is triggered, I need the code to also move information from column BZ and place it in cell CZ2 at teh same time and I have no idea how to change the code.

Comment: and how you want trigger that action?

Comment: Your this question is the same as [your new question of your this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71028326/using-googlesheet-appscript-to-pull-an-id-from-one-column-to-a-cell-when-another/71028600?noredirect=1#comment125701516_71028600)? if it's so, how about my reply?

Comment: @Vector The code is triggered by placing a 1 in cell BY2

Comment: @Tanaike, I need this code to do more, I need it to also move that same row from BZ into Cell CB2 When it is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the cell "B" to "BW" when the cell "BY" is edited to `1`.
- You want to run the script by a trigger.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save the script. When you use this script, please put `1` to the column "BY" of "AutoQuoteDataBase" sheet. By this, the script is run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "AutoQuoteDataBase" || range.columnStart != 77 || range.getValue() != 1) return;
  sheet.getRange("B" + range.rowStart).copyTo(sheet.getRange("BW" + range.rowStart), {contentsOnly: true});
```

#### Note:

- This script is run by a simple trigger of `onEdit`. So when you directly run this script, an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` occurs. Please be careful about this.
- For example, when you want to copy the column "B" to the column "BW" by checking the column "BY" without using `onEdit`, you can also use the following script. In this case, you can directly run this function with the script editor.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AutoQuoteDataBase");
      var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
      var values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:BY" + lastRow).getValues();
      var res = values.map(r => [r[76] == 1 ? r[1] : null]);
      if (res.length == 0) return;
      srcSheet.getRange("BW2:BW" + (res.length + 1)).setValues(res);
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: the first code is what I want if I add "sheet.getRange("BZ" + range.rowStart).copyTo(sheet.getRange("CA2" ), {contentsOnly: true});" to the end, how can I run this directly?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. About `the first code is what I want if I add "sheet.getRange("BZ" + range.rowStart).copyTo(sheet.getRange("CA2" ), {contentsOnly: true});" to the end, how can I run this directly?`, this is your new question? Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your initial question and your reply. I apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to correctly understand your reply. If your reply is a new question, how about resolving your question from your initial question?